# Problem with Window Titlebars when not maximized in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity

For the last few days I am facing the problem that Non-Maximized windows are not showing the titlebar properly and its difficult to drag the window as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Text Editor on Ubuntu 16.04 & Unity 7.4]

Answer (score 2):

Hold down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, left-click/hold in the white space in the window, and drag the window to your position of choice. This will allow the menus to be visible again.

Comment: This is not a permanent solution but thanks. I was unaware of this tip!

Comment: @M.AhmadZafar Windows getting stuck under the top panel happens on occasion, so the only permanent solution would have been to delete the gedit preferences.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: @M.AhmadZafar by moving the gedit window out from under the top panel, you've already fixed what would have been wrong with the gedit prefs. There is no permanent way to make sure that this never happens again with gedit, or any other app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a long-term fix, but I have found a work-around.

Go to `System settings` --> `Appearance` --> `Behavior`

Under `Menus visibility` check the `Displayed on mouse hovering` option .

Menus will now be displayed when you hover the cursor over them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me.